# How to clean duplicate entries from the left side of a joint dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

**For visualization** and export of a wide, left-joint dataframe in pandas, I would like to remove repeated entries from the left side.

What do I mean by this?

```
import pandas as pd

cities = pd.DataFrame().append([
    {"Name": "Peter", "City": "Boston"},
    {"Name": "Paul", "City": "Houston"}
    ], ignore_index=True)
emails = pd.DataFrame().append(    [
        {"Name": "Peter", "Email": "peter@company.com"},
        {"Name": "Peter", "Email": "peter@university.edu"},
        {"Name": "Paul", "Email": "paul@company.com"},
    ], ignore_index=True)

print(cities.merge(emails))
```

This prints

```
    Name     City                 Email
0  Peter   Boston     peter@company.com
1  Peter   Boston  peter@university.edu
2   Paul  Houston      paul@company.com
```

What I would like to print is

```
    Name     City                 Email
0  Peter   Boston     peter@company.com
1                  peter@university.edu
2   Paul  Houston      paul@company.com
```

How can I achieve this, ideally during the join so I don't have to keep track of which columns are from the former left and right sides?

Comment: Try this: `cities.merge(emails).groupby(['Name', 'City', 'Email']).size()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) per all columns and then set `''` in [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = cities.merge(emails)

df1 = df.mask(df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated), '')
print (df1)
    Name     City                 Email
0  Peter   Boston     peter@company.com
1                  peter@university.edu
2   Paul  Houston      paul@company.com
```

Comment: I edited my MWE, but I guess `duplicated()` will help me a lot already!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @jezreal's answer, which unfortunately determines duplicates for each column individually, I came up with this:

```
df = cities.merge(emails)
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=cities.columns), df.columns.isin(cities.columns)] = ""
print(df)
```

I wasn't able to get `df.mask` working with this approach, which would be a bit more explicit, but I'm okay with `df.loc`:

```
    Name     City                 Email
0  Peter   Boston     peter@company.com
1                  peter@university.edu
2   Paul  Houston      paul@company.com
```